# What is the max size of an In-App package you can host with Apple?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

It is now possible to host your In-App purchases with Apple in the form of a .pkg file, this is really great news since and it means that Apple can now handle the verification process regarding users and what they already purchases.

But my application has an in-app purchase for extra content, in the form of a non-consumable item and the problem is that I've got lots of information in there... Photos (both normal and retina versions), many short video clips and more...

How big can my package file be?

Comment: do you know how to create these pkg files? Xcode create xcarchives, not pkg files.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Apple will allow you to upload package files up to **2GB in size**. This is also the same size limit for your application.

To upload your Apple hosted In-App purchase you must use the Application Loader.

For more details you can check out the following guide by Apple: [Using Application Loader](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/UsingApplicationLoader.pdf)

Page 30 of that document:

> When sending a content package for your non-consumable In-App Purchase
>   for Apple hosting, keep the following in mind:
>
> 1. **The size of the content package cannot exceed 2GB**.
> 2. The content package must not contain any executable code or symlinks that point outside the content directory.
> 3. You can deliver a new package once your In-App Purchase is live. For your new content to go live, you must submit it for review and
>      approval in iTunes Connect.
> 4. To remove files, if your In-App Purchase is not live, uncheck “Host Content with Apple” and resend your package. You cannot remove
>      files once you deliver your package and your In-App Purchase is live.

Comment: @Daniel can you please tell me how to create this required pkg file? Apple says it is just a folder, but it is not. I have tried to use a folder with Application Loader and it does not accepts. Xcode will not create pkg files either. Please save me! :D

Comment: I want to upload a MOV file but xcode considers as an executable. What can I do?

Comment: @Daniel how one can confirm : "The content package must not contain any executable code or symlinks that point outside the content directory." ? I am facing issue because of this.

Comment: @Daniel May be this could be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810971/strange-error-of-executable-while-creating-archive-pkg-with-pdf-content-to-host

Comment: Anybody is sure about the size limitation per application?

Comment: @Dainel Hi..Is there any size limitations for hosting content per application?If any please let me know what is the maximum amount of size we can host per application.

Answer (score 0):

While the size of an individual hosted file is limited to 2GB (exactly 2 billion bytes) when I attempted to upload several such individual files, I ran into a second undocumented 5 GB total size limit for Apple hosted content in a single app. I filed a bug report and have not yet re-tested this limit to see if it has been increased.