# Strange error of executable while creating archive/.pkg with PDF content to Host at Apple

Tags: ios, ios6, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I have enabled In App Purchase for my an application and integrated the classes. The type of purchase is `Non-Consumable` and I mark Host Content with Apple to YES. When I want to host content with Apple I need to provide Hosted Content Package.

Here are the steps I am following to create the Package (.pkg):

- File -> New -> Project... -> Other (iOS) -> In-App Purchase Content. New project gets created.
- Put data to this project , making necessary change with .plist file and choose: Product -> Archive.
- After this step, I am getting the error at the time of validation:

[image]

Once I was able to create the package with Test3 & Test 4. But at the time of creating orignal package other than demo, it just throws this error every time.

Here is the ref url: [Configuring and Creating App Store Hosted Content for iOS 6 In-App Purchases](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Configuring_and_Creating_App_Store_Hosted_Content_for_iOS_6_In-App_Purchases#Archiving_the_Hosted_Content_Package)

Comment: Shouldn't files like that be in `.../Contents/Resources`?

Comment: @trojanfoe this is the structure created by Xcode template itself.BTW let me try adding the folder with Resource too.

Comment: No, I am thinking about Mac apps, not iOS apps, so ignore me.

Comment: @trojanfoe not an issue. I tried the same for iOS too .. .but that didn;t work.The package gets created ,but still that shows the error.

Comment: It's not the permissions on the file is it?  `chmod 0644 gatesofzion.pdf` on the *source version* and retry.

Comment: Sorry .. I am not getting how to check this, especially for the PDF file ? But somehow,I changed the access rights of this file though Get Info, then also it not working.How to check : chmod 0644 gatesofzion.pdf

Comment: I don't think Finder's *Get Info* gives you all the information (it seems to exclude the executable bits).  Start `Terminal.app` and `cd` into your source directory and do the `chmod` above.

Comment: FWIW, trojanfoe's solution works for me.

Answer (score 3):

Open Terminal, type 'cd ' then drag the folder containing your files into the Terminal window and hit enter, then use the commands `ls -l yourfile.extension` and `chmod -x yourfile.extension`

replace yourfile.extension with actual file name of yours

What is actually happening is that mac osx includes executables bit by default.
By Chmod you are removing it which is required for ios hosted app content.